# Should I avoid hitting the database on tests as a shortcut to fill object with valid data?

Tags: c#, sql-server, unit-testing, testing, functional-testing

I have a test suite which works against a dedicated copy of the real database. The application creates a complex object by filling it from the database and it would be a lot of work do create one "manually" or mocking one to bring it to a valid state. So I ran a database query from the tests in order to have a valid object (not to verify that I *integrate* with the database correctly). It was working blazing fast. Especially after the first call MSSQL was caching it and the query ran in less than 1 ms.

Are there any arguments why I should avoid doing this? If it's because speed when the database is on the same network it's working fast? It seems that most literature out there wouldn't recommend doing this - but why?

**EDIT - To answer my own question:** "unit tests" means that each test is autonomous, if you touch the database one test could modify it and affect another test. Even though transactions can solve it, it's still not quite in the "spirit" of "unit tests" and make them a bit cumbersome. So this should be avoided but not under all circumstances, if I have no choice I'll access the database in transaction which will make sure it won't affect other tests.

Comment: I think you are trying to write Integration tests, which definitely require a DB (Mock though!) . You should be able to create database on the start of test run and  drop it after running all tests.  This way it is easier to clean up the mess piled up by the tests and start a fresh database after each test run gives you control over your tests.  Also make sure you are the only person who is running the tests at one instance. If multiple people are running tests on the same DB instance then DB may get messed up and produce wrong results.

Comment: That's a big "depends", depending on what you are actually testing. If your data access code returns an IQueryable you could mock it with a class that returns any container, even an array as an IQueryable without any changes. Or you could use LocalDB or SQLite as a disposable database

Comment: Unit testing has become a religion.  The more a system is replaced with impostors just for the sake of testing convenience and timeliness, the lower the level of usefulness such results have when reporting to stake-holders.  Testing with a DB is integration testing and one does not mock-out an airplane aileron when testing a FMC just because the servos are slow!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a principle some people follow - that you should never hit the database - but my experience is that sometimes, trying too hard to avoid the database creates these giant tests, over-use of mocks, or a strange and brittle data access interface. Search about for [test-induced design damage](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=test-induced%20design%20damage) for more on this idea.

For my part, I'm happy to access a database as part of tests. You can often do write tests if you can wrap the whole test in a transaction, too.

Comment: SQLite or LocalDB can be used as test databases that can also work on the build server, if one doesn't want to use a SQL Server instance just for testing. SQLite could even be created in-memory

Answer (score 1):

We split up our tests in unit tests and integration tests/dlls. The unit tests cannot go to the db, the integration tests can.

Keep in mind that having a lot of integration tests can seriously slow your build. I can run all my unit tests in minutes while running the integration tests take over an hour.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define for yourself WHAT you want to test? Do you want a test that simply checks if your **API** does what it should? Then you can mock even that single database-entity from your tests and test if **your** code goes right. Need an integration-test including database-traffic, network, ... ? Test your real-world scenarios including the code that is neccessary to get and manage your entities. So it depends on what you want to test and what you expect from those tests.

Considering the DB-performance should play no effect on this decission as you cannot relate on any DB-specific optimization in your tests. What happens when you decide to change the DBMS to something without this kind of optimization? Than your tests will fail which is doubtfully what you want. Performance should never affect **what** to test, however it might play a rule on **how** to do so.